# Find the series in C programming

Tags: c

Help me to find the sum of this series x^1+x^4+x^7+.. to n terms

```
          #include<conio.h>
          #include<math.h>
           int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
            int n;
            float x;
            int l=1;

           printf(" Enter the value of x :");
           scanf("%f",&x);
             for (int i = 1; i <=n; i++)
               {
                 l = pow(x,l+3);
               }
             printf("x ^ %d + power %d",x,l);
             return 0;
            }
```

Comment: Where is `n` initialised?

Comment: `l+3`-> `1+i*3`.

Comment: Is x a float or an int? The result seems l and is int.

Comment: `l = ` -> `l +=`.

Comment: Change `l=1`->`l=0`.

Comment: If in int, do not use `pow()`.

Comment: If in float, change cleanly to float.

Comment: are you sure about `int l;`? BTW: `l` is easily confused with `1` in lots of typefaces ... maybe choose a different identifier?

Comment: Replace `pow` with a running multiplication for starters.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want :) i've commented the errors

```
    #include<conio.h>
    #include<math.h>
    int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    int n;
    float x;
    float l=0,i=0;
  // initialize n first to determine how far the sum should go
   printf(" Enter the value of n :");
   scanf("%d",&n);

    printf(" Enter the value of x :");
    scanf("%f",&x);
     for (int i = 0; i <n; i++)
       { //l+= pow(x,(i*3)+1); is equivilant to l= l+ pow(x,i+3); which i assume that's what you wanted to do
         // l should be a float as well not int since x is a float
         l+= pow(x,(i*3)+1);
         if(i!=n-1)printf(" %f^%d +",x,i*3+1);
        else printf("%f^%d",x,i*3+1);
       }
       printf("\nResult of the sum is %f",l);
     return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem in this loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i <=n; i++)
{
    l = pow(x,l+3);
}
```

You set `l` every time and then in the end it has the value of the last assignment, but you wanted to add them all up. Also, it should be `i` in the `pow` call, not `l+3`, instead you should move that step of 3 to the loop increment. Try this:

```
int l = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i+=3)
{
    l += pow(x, i);
}
```

Also make sure that you initialize `n`, you should probably read it in using `scanf`, just like you do with `x`.

Also note that since `l` is `int`, it's going to be truncated every time. If you don't want that, you should declare it as `float` instead, and depending on how precise the result should be, you might even want to consider `double`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
  double x;
  unsigned n;

  fprintf(stderr, "enter x and n :");
  /* enter x as a double and x as an unsigned number, both on the same line, and check 2 values are enter */
  if (scanf("%lg %u", &x, &n) != 2)
    puts("invalid or missing values");
  else {
    double r = 0; /* sum initialization */
    int p = 1; /* the power to apply, 1 then 4 then 7 etc */

    while (n--) { /* have to sum n times */
      r += pow(x, p); /* x^1+x^4+x^7+... */
      p += 3; /* next power value */
    }

    printf("%g\n", r);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

if I well understand *n* terms `x^y` must be added rather than the last pow is `x^n`, I use double for *x* and of course the result ( *r* )

---

Executions :

```
enter x and n :1.2 3
6.85678

enter x and n :2 1
2
```

---

Check with *bc* :

```
% bc
bc 1.06.95
Copyright 1991-1994, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2004, 2006 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
For details type `warranty'. 
scale=6
1.2 + 1.2^4 + 1.2^7
6.856780
```

Comment: @AayushKc I added comments, difficult to do more ;-)

Comment: @AayushKc is it ok for you ?

Answer (score 0):

**Multiple operations on floating point numbers tend to compound rounding errors very quickly, so if you can minimize the number of operations, always do**.

Now if you recognize that your polynomial is a Geometric series (see [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)) with a = x and r = x^3, then we have the following pseudo-code algorithm (note no loops!):

```
Case 1 (x == 0): Sum == 0 regardless of n.

Case 2 (x == 1): Sum == n.

Case 3 (x any other number): Sum == x*(1-(x^(3*n)))/(1-(x^3)).

Case 4 (n==infinity and -1<x<1): Sum == x/(1-(x^3)).
```

I trust you can code accordingly.